# Drawing Line on PictureBox's Image But not coming through entire height or width

Tags: c#, picturebox, system.drawing

I am drawing line on picture box's  vertically and horizontally but lines are not comming in full length they appear less in height and width i am drawing images in on frame event of a camera and then displaying lines on image but they are not comming completely my code is as below
Picture box's size mode is Zoom

```
    private void onFrameEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        uEye.Camera Camera = sender as uEye.Camera;
        Int32 s32MemID;

        Bitmap bmp = null;

        Camera.Memory.GetActive(out s32MemID);
       // bmpbackup = null;

        Camera.Memory.CopyToBitmap(s32MemID, out bmp);
        try
        {
            bmp.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);

            DisplayWindow.Image = bmp;

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {


        }

        if (Const.cal == true)
        {
            g1.DrawLine(p, new Point(lastPoint4LeftClick.X, 0), new Point(lastPoint4LeftClick.X, DisplayWindow.Size.Height));
            g1.DrawLine(p, new Point(0, lastPoint4RightClick.Y), new Point(DisplayWindow.Size.Width, lastPoint4RightClick.Y));
            g1.DrawLine(p, new Point(last2ndPoint4LeftClick.X, 0), new Point(last2ndPoint4LeftClick.X,DisplayWindow.ClientSize.Height));
            g1.DrawLine(p, new Point(0, last2ndPoint4RightClick.Y), new Point(DisplayWindow.Size.Width, last2ndPoint4RightClick.Y));
            g1.DrawLine(p, new Point(0, 0), new Point(0, 1));
            Const.Xcalfactor = Math.Abs(lastPoint4LeftClick.X - last2ndPoint4LeftClick.X);
            Const.Ycalfactor = Math.Abs(lastPoint4RightClick.Y - last2ndPoint4RightClick.Y);
        }


        GC.Collect();
    }
```

Comment: where did g1 come from?

Comment: Its a g1=displayWIndow.createGraphics()

Comment: `createGraphics` is almost never the right way to draw, nothing persists.  Do your drawing in the Paint Event

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in CopyToBitmap:
It says in the manual that it returns a copy of the image in memory but it actually gives out a reference to the image.
In your case it means that by the time you draw the lines, a new image is being drawn in the buffer and overwrites parts of your image.
If high FPS rate is not important to you, copy the bitmap to a new instance and then draw and render it in a separate thread.
I have good results in display using 15 FPS.